# batch insert millions of records to hive using hive sql?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to prepare sample data for test on hive table **stored as parquet format**. Table look like this:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE exps (sn STRING, buildNum STRING, shortProdName
STRING, userIV STRING, cfs STRUCT<version : STRING, name : STRING,
objArray : ARRAY<STRUCT<id : STRING, properties : INT>> >) STORED AS PARQUET;
```

Then I write a sql file say "sample.sql" which contains millions of lines of sql insert command.

> $ /opt/hive-0.13.1/bin/hive -f sample.sql

It will result in hive start lots of map-reduce jobs and execute one by one, which is quite slow.

So my question is: is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does sample.sql contains?

Comment: lots of lines of insert like:     INSERT INTO TABLE EXPS select '"0017C5CAE03A"', '"4.0.3"','"TZ-205"', '"keu3zm4ctkzjweh8"', named_struct('Version','1','name','Default', 'objArray',array(named_struct('id','WLAN','properties',50973,'ZoneType',1,'SonicPointProfHandle',0),named_struct('id','WAN','properties',50973,'ZoneType',1,'SonicPointProfHandle',0))) from dummy;

Answer (score 1):

There is no dummy table in Hive, so sample.sql won't work.

Since you need to try parquet format in hive using SQL, my suggestion is

1. Load the data in a relational database like mysql.
2. Import data from relational database to HDFS using Apache Sqoop.
3. Create a Hive table as parquet format
4. Load the data from HDFS to Hive table.

Answer (score -3):

i am not so professional in SQL but i think this is only way to insert data to database

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(c1,c2,...) VALUES(v1,v2,...);
```

Comment: this is the standard insert command, but the OP is talking about batch insert, so obviously this will not help them...